# Migrate from MBR to UEFI with an encrypted system partition

Tags: boot, opensuse, uefi, grub2

I had the idea of converting a live and running openSUSE installation from MBR to GPT/UEFI. I followed [this tutorial](http://bramp.net/blog/2010/08/converting-mbr-to-gpt-without-deleting-your-partitions/) and successfully converted disk keeping partitions and associated data. My original setup was the following:

```
/dev/sda1 ext4 /boot
/dev/sda2 LVM
    /dev/root/root ext4 /
    /dev/root/home ext4 /home
```

After converting disk to GPT, as I suspected, Linux didn't boot. BIOS didn't show me the option of MBR-booting Linux which now lives on a GPT disk. OK, it's time to setup `grub2-efi`.

I need to install `grub2efi` on `/dev/sda`'s EFI partition, which is 156MB large.
First, I have converted (read "backed up, formatted and restored files") `/boot` into VFAT as required by EFI. I also double-checked that the partition type is EFI Boot.
I ran a Live openSUSE to mount & chroot into the root partition

```
# cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sda2 root
# vgchange -a y suse
# mkdir /mnt/suse
# mount /dev/suse/root /mnt/suse
# mount /dev/suse/home /mnt/suse/home
# mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/suse/boot
# for i in /dev /dev/pts /sys /proc; do mount -B $i /mnt/suse$i; done
# chroot /mnt/suse
```

I tried with YaST Boot Loader configuration, and later with `grub2-efi-install` but the result is always the following: when I EFI-boot into Linux I get GRUB's rescue console with error "unknown filesystem".

My current partition setup is the following

```
/dev/sda1 vfat /boot #only this changed
/dev/sda2 LVM
    /dev/root/root ext4 /
    /dev/root/home ext4 /home
```

Question straightforward: how do I make grub boot the encrypted system partition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution: split `/boot` in two

1. Backed up all `/boot` files
2. Removed `/dev/sda1` partition (it was 156MB in my case)
3. Created a new smaller `/dev/sda1` partition with EFI-boot partition type, formatted with VFAT, mounted to /boot/efi, size 50MB in my case
4. Created a new `/dev/sda5` (YaST assigned this number to me, it should be a sda2) partition between the just created `/boot/efi` and the system partition, mounted as `/boot` and formatted ext4
5. Restored `/boot` files from backup
6. Configured grub to resume from `sda5` instead of `sda2`
7. Ran `mkinitrd` and `grub2-efi-install`
8. Rebooted

Now I have an almost perfectly working full-UEFI laptop (Windows already booted from UEFI). Almost because grub is missing the theme.

#### Explanation: why separate partitions?

UEFI and GRUB are very strict: the EFI unencrypted partition is required to load GRUB, the bootloader, into memory.

If I didn't have an encrypted system volume I could easily skip the second part. But the EFI partition only holds the bootloader, which is not the same as the **kernel**. In order to load the kernel, we need an unencrypted, another unencrypted partition that holds the `initrd` file which gets loaded by grub.

The concept is simple: grub fires up from EFI partition and immediately seeks for initrd in the `/boot` partition, which eventually finds that the system volume is encrypted and asks for the key(s)